# Error with heroku db:push

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, heroku

This is my error message when I do a `heroku db:push`
I think my sqlite3 is broken. Any idea how I can do a clean db:push to heroku?

```
Sending schema
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0025 p:-539322560 s:0105 b:0105 l:000104 d:000104 TOP   
c:0024 p:---- s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 CFUNC  :require
c:0023 p:0053 s:0099 b:0099 l:000098 d:000098 METHOD /Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
c:0022 p:0029 s:0092 b:0092 l:000088 d:000091 BLOCK  /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:6
c:0021 p:0035 s:0089 b:0089 l:000088 d:000088 TOP    /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:2
c:0020 p:---- s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 FINISH
c:0019 p:---- s:0085 b:0085 l:000084 d:000084 CFUNC  :require
c:0018 p:0071 s:0081 b:0081 l:000077 d:000080 BLOCK  /Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58
c:0017 p:0189 s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 METHOD /Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35
c:0016 p:0011 s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 TOP    /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:1
c:0015 p:---- s:0069 b:0069 l:000068 d:000068 FINISH
c:0014 p:---- s:0067 b:0067 l:000066 d:000066 CFUNC  :require
c:0013 p:0053 s:0063 b:0063 l:000062 d:000062 METHOD /Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
c:0012 p:0012 s:0056 b:0056 l:000044 d:000055 BLOCK  /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249
c:0011 p:0015 s:0054 b:0054 l:000048 d:000053 BLOCK  /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72
c:0010 p:0019 s:0052 b:0052 l:000051 d:000051 METHOD <internal:prelude>:10
c:0009 p:0051 s:0049 b:0049 l:000048 d:000048 METHOD /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69
c:0008 p:0011 s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 METHOD /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249
c:0007 p:0098 s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 METHOD /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:25
c:0006 p:0193 s:0035 b:0035 l:000034 d:000034 METHOD /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:54
c:0005 p:0021 s:0023 b:0023 l:000022 d:000022 METHOD /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119
c:0004 p:0031 s:0018 b:0018 l:0016e8 d:0016e8 METHOD /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/taps-0.3.23.pre1/lib/taps/schema.rb:17
c:0003 p:0331 s:0013 b:0012 l:0014e8 d:001e28 EVAL   /Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/taps-0.3.23.pre1/bin/schema:32
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0014e8 d:0014e8 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/taps-0.3.23.pre1/bin/schema:32:in `<main>'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/taps-0.3.23.pre1/lib/taps/schema.rb:17:in `dump_table'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:54:in `connect'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:25:in `adapter_class'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `tsk_require'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:69:in `check_requiring_thread'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:72:in `block in check_requiring_thread'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:249:in `block in tsk_require'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `rescue in require'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `require'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/sweska/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
```

Comment: Thanks @simone for the formatting! How did you do that? I already used ``, but it wasn't so nicely formatted as you did it :)

Comment: Ok I got this to work... apparently I had both Homebrew and Macports installed with postgreSQL. I removed Homebrew and postgreSQL from Macports and this seems to work now. There might have been some conflicts with sqlite3 installation.

Comment: No problem @sayanee. To format a block of code, simply indent it with 4 spaces or press the `{}` button on the editor.